# Locking an attribute after it has a certain value

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model where if it is given a certain status, the status can never be changed again. I've tried to achieve this by putting in a before_save on the model  to check what the status is and raise an exception if it is set to that certain status.

Problem is this -

```
 def raise_if_exported
   if self.exported?
     raise Exception, "Can't change an exported invoice's status"
   end
 end
```

which works fine but when I initially set the status to exported by doing the following -

```
 invoice.status = "Exported"
 invoice.save
```

the exception is raised because the status is already set the exported on the model not the db (I think)

So is there a way to prevent that attribute from being changed once it has been set to "Exported"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an validator for your requirement

```
class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base

  validates_each :status do |record, attr, value|
     if ( attr == :status and status_changed? and status_was == "Exported")
       record.errors.add(:status, "you can't touch this")
     end
  end

end
```

Now

```
invoice.status= "Exported"
invoice.save # success

invoice.status= "New"
invoice.save # error
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `ActiveModel::Dirty` to track the changes, instead of checking current status:

```
def raise_if_exported
  if status_changed? && status_was == "Exported"
    raise "Can't change an exported invoice's status"
  end
end
```

Try this, only *if* you really want that exception to raise on save. If not, check it during the validation like @Trip suggested

See [this page](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html) for more detail.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go for a mix of @Trip and @Sikachu's answers:

```
validate :check_if_exported

def check_if_exported
  if status_changed? && status_was.eql?("Exported")
    errors.add(:status, " cannot be changed once exported.")
  end
end
```

Invalidating the model is a better response than just throwing an error, unless you *reeeally* want to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Try Rails built in validation in your model :

```
validate :check_if_exported

def check_if_exported
  if self.exported?
    errors.add(:exported_failure, "This has been exported already.")
  end
end
```